# Questions about customizing bootstrap progress bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, styling

First question: In my Bootstrap progress bar, I added a label to show the status of the bar. However, bootstrap centers the text by default, but I want it to float right, and be right next to the end of the progress bar. I've tried putting the text in an h6 tag, then styling it with `float: right`, however that didn't seem to change anything. So, how can I float the text right?

Second question: I also want to be able to change the color of the bar, but have it still have the stripe and animation that Bootstrap does. Is there some way to do this or no? So ideally, the bar could be like purple or something, but still be striped and show the animation.

Below is the picture of what I'm currently working with, if it helps at all:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBKxI.png)

Here's the code I'm using to make the above:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 76%">
        <h6 style="font-weight: thin; font-size: 13px;">Complete!</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float: right;` is not working because the progress-bar uses flexbox property.

Try `align-self: flex-end;` on your `<h6>` tag.

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 76%">
               <h6 style="font-weight: thin; font-size: 13px; align-self: flex-end;">Complete!</h6>
            </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! That seemed to move the text, but do you know if there is a way to change the color of the bar?

Comment: @orph-c I've updated my answer for changing the background color of the progress-bar. Can you accept the answer so that it'll be marked as resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Done! Thank you so much